# how to pass JMSDestination for ActiveMQ in the JMS request headers through JMS point to point sampler using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jndi, activemq-artemis, jmeter-5.0, request-headers

We are using JMS point to point sampler for sending messages to different artemis queues in JMeter, while sending the request we need to pass the same queue as used in JNDI properties for JMSDestination in the request headers for JMS point to point sampler.
For expample if we have queues A, B and C. For first execution queue used should be A and JMSDestination in the JMS request headers should be JMSDestination ActiveMQQueue[A], for second execution queue used should be B and JMSDestination in the JMS request headers should be JMSDestination ActiveMQQueue[C], for third execution queue used should be B and JMSDestination in the JMS request headers should be JMSDestination ActiveMQQueue[C]?
We are facing issue only with JMS request headers all other places are reading the queues correctly, any solution for this will be much helpful.

how to pass the parameters in JMS request headers while JMS point to point sampler in JMeter?

Comment: The library you use to send the JMS message will set the `JMSDestination`. This is not something the client application should be doing. See more details in the [JavaDoc for `Message`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSDestination-javax.jms.Destination-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, at least not with [JMS Point-to-Point](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) sampler and not with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

Here is [how it's handled currently](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/protocol/jms/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/Utils.java#L129):

```
sb.append("JMSDestination   ").append(msg.getJMSDestination()).append('\n');
```

so you cannot overwrite the value unless you amend JMeter source code or [develop your own version of the JMS Point-to-Point sampler](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/protocol/jms/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/Utils.java#L129)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I am unable to open the jmeter.bat file from the above URL, getting Error: Unable to access jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar
errorlevel=1. Any fix for this, how launch the customized jmeter from the above URL

Comment: If you mean Github - there is unchanged version there, I just pointed where and how the header is set. Once you change the header value according to your requirements you can [build your own JMeter version](https://github.com/apache/jmeter#test-builds) and use it for testing. You can also find [How to Develop a JMeter Plugin: Intro & Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) article useful